# Dealing with segmentation fault in recursive binary search

Tags: c++, binary-search

How can I prevent a segmentation fault with a recursive binary search that does not find the number it it is looking for in the array.

```
int recursive_binary_search(int A[], int beg, int end, int key)
{
    if(end < beg)
        return -1;
    int mid = beg + end / 2;
    if(A[mid] == key)
        return mid;
    else if(A[mid] > key)
        return recursive_binary_search(A, beg, mid - 1, key);
    else
        return recursive_binary_search(A, mid + 1, end, key);
}
```

Comment: Do you handle `std::exception` at caller function?

Comment: Let me just take that part out.

Comment: your mid is not really a mid - missing parenthesis around beg + end

Comment: Does 'end' denote the last entry in the list or is it - as with stl - the entry after the end? If the latter, shouldn't you be writing `if(end <= beg)`?

Comment: e.g. if you have one element in A, would beg = 0 and end = 1?

Comment: @kfsone. Functions is being called one minus the size of the array so `end` is the last entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forgot the `()` around the definition for `mid`.

Correcting the definition to

```
int mid = (beg + end) / 2;
```

fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following code might be sufficient,

```
int recursive_binary_search(int A[], int beg, int end, int key)
{
    if(end < beg)
        cout<<"\nKey not Found";
    int mid = beg + end / 2;
    if(A[mid] == key)
        return mid;
    else if(A[mid] > key)
        return recursive_binary_search(A, beg, mid - 1, key);
    else
        return recursive_binary_search(A, mid + 1, end, key);
}
```